# Laptop's battery seems dead but "upower -i" shows nothing wrong

Tags: power-management, laptop, battery

Recently my laptop's battery stopped working suddenly. I can't turn on my computer without the computer charger, and when it's running and that I'm unplugging the cable the laptop shows black screen and shuts down immediately.
I'm using an Acer Aspire E-571G.

The battery is Li-ion, 10.8V, 4400 mAh/48Wh.

So I checked more info about the battery using the "upower -i" command. And nothing weird showed up.

```
$ upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT1
  native-path:          BAT1
  vendor:               LG
  model:                Li_Ion_4000mA
  serial:               00B8
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              mer. 17 févr. 2021 16:25:01 CET (3 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               charging
    warning-level:       none
    energy:              16,3404 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         23,0256 Wh
    energy-full-design:  47,52 Wh
    energy-rate:         0,0864 W
    voltage:             11,719 V
    percentage:          70%
    capacity:            48,4545%
    technology:          lithium-ion
    icon-name:          'battery-full-charging-symbolic'
```

If I get a new battery, will the problem be solved ? Or is it an hardware problem in the laptop ?

Comment: Your battery is showing that it can provide a maximum of 11.719 volts, which is insufficient for many notebooks. Time to get a new battery.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. On the battery it's written 10.8V so it's not really different from 11.719V, isn't it ?